on GCP, IaP not on by default for HTTPRoute & public Gateway, how to enforce to avoid public access
We use HTTPRoute + Gateway on GKE. We also have IaP in front of our applications. However, when I create a new HTTPRoute to e.g. ArgoCD or MLFlow, it is by default not protected. I need to remember going into the UI and manually enabling IaP for that application in the Console.
Is there any way to set a rule in GKE globally that any HTTPRoute needs to be IaP protected for a specific gateway?
